# nmap to check battery installed or not

Tags: php, networking, nmap, wmic

I'm working on a project which scan the LAN and display reslut in html/PHP/mysql using NMAP Commands. Similar application to spiceworks.

In spiceworks they said they categorized their nmap output according to following criteria.

Laptops: Machines that respond to the WMI or SSH ports and are found to have a **battery installed.**

Desktops: Machines that respond to the WMI or SSH ports, **but do not have a battery installed and are not running a server operating system.**

Now I can categorized my results according to open ports butIi can't find battery status (available or not). Is there any nmap command to find battery status in given IP? Or do you have any idea what they are using to find battery installes during the scan?

Comment: ok.i found this wmic command to get the battery info.  wmic /node:192.168.12.82 /namespace:"\\root\CIMV2" path Win32_Battery get BatteryStatus.  and i can get this output into csv file also.  but if i run this php shell_exec command it doesnt display anything in web page.  echo shell_exec('wmic /node:192.168.12.79 /namespace:"\\root\CIMV2" path Win32_Battery get BatteryStatus');

Comment: Which service should tell a client programe that it uses a battery the only I can imagine is SNMP? And how do your Win32 commands reveal linux laptops with batteries?

Answer (score 1):

```
powercfg -DEVICEQUERY all_devices|find "Battery" >battery.log
set Empty=Y
for /f %%i in (battery.log) do set empty=N
if %empty%==Y (
      ...
del battery.log
) else (
...
del battery.log
) 
pause
```

Comment: This only works locally doesn't it,.. it's not available remote and not via nmap. Explanations would be nice.

Comment: Dan you are right, I forgot to mention that I don't know how to run this on a remote system. There must be a way to do that though.